# Convert Dictionary<string, object> to a collection of objects with key

Tags: c#

Is there a way to convert `Dictionary<string, obj>` to collection of objects such that each single object in the collection includes the key as another property

Here is the class def for obj

```
class someclass
{
  string property1;
  string property2;
}
```

After conversion, I am expecting each object in the collection to be like

```
obj.property1
obj.property2
obj.Key
```

I have been struggling with this since along time and I seek some help. any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can already see from the answers, you can get a list of anonymous types, or a list of `Tuple<,,>` (three-tuples). You could also write a new class with the desired members, and then create a list of instances of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
var myCollection = from de in myDictionary 
                   select new
                   {
                       de.Value.property1,
                       de.Value.property2,
                       de.Key
                   }.ToList();  // or .ToArray()
```

should do the trick.

That will return a List of a new anonymous type with the properties you requested.

Comment: But is there a method `ToCollection()`?

Comment: Good catch.  Updated the answer.  (I did say *something like* lol).

Answer (score 2):

You could also(in addition to the [anonymous type apporach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11567427/284240)) use a `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>`:

```
var list= dictionary
         .Select(kv => Tuple.Create(kv.Value.property1, kv.Value.property2, kv.Key))
         .ToList();

foreach(var item in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine("property1:{0 property2:{1} key:{2}"
                     , item.Item1
                     , item.Item2
                     , item.Item3);
}
```

The advantage over an anonymous type is that you can return the `Tuple` easily from a method.

**Edit**: A third option(my favorite) is simply to create instances of a class that you've declared somewhere. That's the ideal way. I don't know why i thought that you want a class "on the fly".

```
class someOtherClass
{
    public string property1{ get; set; };
    public string property2{ get; set; };
    public string Key{ get; set; };
}

List<someOtherClass> objects = dictionary
.Select(kv => new someOtherClass(){
     property1 = kv.Value.property1, 
     property2 = kv.Value.property2, 
     Key       = kv.Key 
 })
.ToList();
```

Comment: Tuples are handy in a pinch, but personally I find myself constantly forgetting what's in Item1, Item2, etc.

Comment: @EricJ.: Yes, me too. They make only sense in a small scope, but in a wider than an anoymous type.

Comment: as an immediate solution EricJ suggestion worked. However, I came to know other good stuff I can use for similar problems. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 1):

You may use anonymous type if you don't want to store the result like this:
In case you just wana use it as datasource for example.

```
var res = myDictionary.Select(pair => new { pair.Key, pair.Value.Property1, pair.Value.Property2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, so this is just a supplement.

You could use arrays of `Length` three:

```
var arrays = myDictionary
    .Select(kv => new[] { kv.Value.property1, kv.Value.property2, kv.Key, });
```

Or you could write a new class

```
class SomeclassAndKey
{
  public string property1;
  public string property1;
  public string Key;
}
```

and then say

```
var someclassAndKeys = myDictionary
    .Select(kv => new SomeclassAndKey { property1 = kv.Value.property1, property2 = kv.Value.property2, Key = kv.Key, });
```

In each case you could append `.ToList()` if you wanted not to defer enumeration and get a full `List<>` out.